# Sum the Calculation of 2 columns

Tags: dax

I have a measure that was calculating the number of sales for a particular product name, but now the business has split the name of the product up in to 2 different products.

I need to sum together the calculations of the now 2 product, i've tried suming them but it just comes up with saying the syntax for calculate is now wrong.

This what i've tried.

*measure = SUM(CALCULATE([Measure1], brand[ProductType3] = "product1"),CALCULATE([Measure1], brand[ProductType3] = "product2")*

How do you sum 2 calculations in the same measure?

Comment: Just  NewMeasure = [FirstMeasure] + [SecondMeasure]

Comment: So i would have to create 2 measures then + them together, thats one way but i'd rather just have 1 total measure.

Comment: you can also make this in one like:

measure = calculate(sum('Table'[SomeColumn]), brand[ProductType3] = "product1")  + calculate(sum('Table'[SomeColumn]), brand[ProductType3] = "product2")

or even:
measure = calculate(sum('Table'[SomeColumn]), brand[ProductType3] in  {"product2", "product1"})

Comment: Both of those didn't work, i got Syntax errors.

Comment: what exacly? Share this syntax error